# How to deal with imbalanced classes in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I am working on a `multi-label` image classification problem with `Keras` and so I utilize functions `flow_from_dataframe()` and `fit_generator()`.

I have about `2000` classes and as you can guess they are highly skewed / imbalanced. After searching a bit I came across with arguments `class_weight` and `classes` and I decided to give them a try. My problem is, I am not sure if I use them correctly. Here is an example:

Let's assume that I have flatten all class occurrences so that I get the following list of (duplicated) labels:

```
labels = ['classD', 'classA', 'classA', 'classC', 'classD', 'classD']
```

And this is the function that computes `classes` and `class_weight`:

```
from collections import Counter
def get_classes_weights(l, n):
    counter = Counter(l).most_common(n)
    classes = [cls for cls, ocu in counter]
    majority = max([ocu for cls, ocu in counter])
    weights = {idx: float(majority/ocu) for idx, (cls, ocu) in enumerate(counter)}
    return classes, weights
```

Let's also assume that I what to consider the top-2 classes only:

```
classes, class_weight = get_classes_weights(labels, 2)
```

This gives:

```
classes: ['classD', 'classA']
```

and:

```
class_weight: {0: 1.0, 1: 1.5}
```

And finally, this is how I use them within the functions:

```
generator_train.flow_from_dataframe(
    classes=classes,
)
```

```
model.fit_generator(
    class_weight=class_weight
)
```

So my question are:

- Is the above the right way to apply weights given that I work on a `multi-label` image classification problem?
- Does my validation set need to be balanced or it is OK if it has been taken from the same distribution as the training set (20% and 80% random selection, respectively)?